# pip installed but not working

Tags: python, bash, shell, pip

I'm trying to use PIP on my server but something weird happens.

So, I have python 2.7.2 installed, in fact when I run `python -V`I get:

```
Python 2.7.2
```

Then, in my `.bashrc` this is what I have:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I'm sure that the last one is correct because when I do `cd $HOME/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, I get:

```
./                            pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info/
../                           setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
README                        setuptools-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/
distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg/  setuptools-2.0.2-py2.7.egg.OLD.1388586026.24
easy-install.pth              setuptools.pth
pip/
```

But then, if I try to use PIP, I get:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` executable is not in your PATH (it *should* be in `/usr/local/bin/pip`, so you need to have `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH or -maybe- `$HOME/.local/usr/local/bin` according to your `.bashrc`).

Comment: Hi, I checked both directories and both do not exist. Maybe I should specify that I'm on a shared hosting. I know that the .local/bin is the one in which for instance git is installed. How can I put the executable of pip in there?

Comment: you may try to find the location of your `pip` executable by running `cd ~;find . -type f -name "pip"`

Comment: thank you, I was able to find it in `./python/bin/pip`so I added the folder into the `.bashrc`and now it works. Do you think I need further  operations for next package installs?

Comment: I guess no, since pip will manage them (except when the packages will have executables utilities, in that case you may need to search for such executables in the same way you did for `pip`). But I suppose your host have documentation for this aspect.